# ¿Como puedo arreglar el problema con mi footer en css y html?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

[image: Imagen de pie de página]

https://gyazo.com/86be1c2d245c830ef81b07749c732a17

Ese es mi pie de página. El texto de la izquierda lo quiero todo en 1 línea y más a la izquierda. He intentado `text-align: left;` pero esto no hace nada o me estropea lo demás.

También quiero el **JOIN NOW** del botón en blanco, lo cual está puesto en todo el código `CSS` pero no se pone en blanco. También un poco más a la derecha el botón.

También he intentado cosas como `overflow-x = hidden`, pero tampoco, eso solo me rompe el pie.

¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Pego aquí todo el código, el pie de página, botón, imagen y texto:

```css
.footer {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.footer img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  footer h4 {
    font-weight: 800;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: 800;
  }
  h4,
  .h4 {
    font-family: Poppins;
    line-height: 1.2;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
    color: #161E2A;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 1.33em;
    margin-block-end: 1.33em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  }
  h4 {
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 1.33em;
    margin-block-end: 1.33em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .row {
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  }
  footer .btn-primary {
    position: fixed;
    width: 50%;
    left: 40px;
    bottom: 0px;
  }
}

footer h4 {
  font-weight: 800;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

footer .btn-primary {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 5;
  left: 50;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 15px 50px;
}


/*.btn-primary:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #0069d9;
        border-color: #0069d9;
      }*/

.btn {
  font-family: Poppins;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 8px 8px 0 0;
  padding: 9.5px 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  letter-spacing: 0.25px;
  border: 2px solid;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer  background-light  " kjb-settings-id="sections_footer_settings_background_color">
  <div class="footer__content">
    <div class="container footer__container media">
      <div class="goals-text">
        <h4>EVERYTHING YOU NEED TO REACH YOUR GOALS</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/kajabi-storefronts-production/themes/2390503/settings_images/PDq55ZFBSeSOxfA8SDFq_eddie.png" class="img-fluid" style="height:170px;">
        <a href="/online-programs" class="btn-primary">JOIN NOW</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). ¿Podrías compartir el HTML del pie de página con los botones, imágenes, texto, etc?

Comment: @OscarGarcia Perdon! Ya he añadido el codigo HTML!

Comment: Unai, por favor, [edita tu pregunta pulsando en este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/376823/edit).

Comment: Hola, Has probado en poner en el código css algo así `.goals-text{ text-align: left;}` y donde pones `h4{display: block;}` has probado poner `display: inline-block` o `footer h4{display: inline-block}` Esa función hace que se ponga todo a la misma altura ( siempre y cuando quepa) Espero que te sirva, quedo atento por si puedo ayudar en algo mas.

Comment: @Nacherasg Gracias por tu comentario, de verdad! Pero si, lo he probado y nada ha cambiado... :/

Comment: Es raro que no haya cambiado nada, es posible que navegador lo tenga cacheado? Alguna vez me ha pasado, tienes dos opciones para borrar esa cache, accediendo desde el modo incógnito o al actualizar la pagina pulsas la tecla **CONTROL+F5** . Te lo digo por experiencia porque alguna vez me ha pasado. A ver si así ocurre algo. Un saludo.

Comment: @Nacherasg Nada... De todas formas, me interesa mas arreglar el tema del color del texto en el botón, tengo todo en blanco y aparece en gris!

Comment: Por lo que veo en el footer tienes el siguiente código de color #f1f1f1, que es como un color gris muy clarito. Prueba en el css a quitar la palabra footer de  `footer .btn-primary
  {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 5;
    left: 50;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 15px 50px;
  }` y dejar solo btn-primary

Comment: @Nacherasg Hecho, pero nada ha cambiado

Comment: @Nacherasg Al final lo he solucionado cambiando el color de fondo del footer, lo he puesto negro y el texto se ha puesto blanco automáticamente... Estaba flipando porque no había ningún error de código para un simple color de texto... Pero bueno, en negro queda bastante bien también! Gracias por tus comentarios, en serio!

Comment: @UnaiSanchez Me alegro de que hayas solucionado el problema, una pena no haber podido ayudarte más, aunque lo que me comentas es bastante raro e inusual, ya que si tu quieres puedes poner todo de un mismo color y no se vea. Un placer.

Comment: @Nacherasg Creo que es mas bien problema del CMS en si, que es KAJABI

Comment: Si es muy probable. Ya que es algo muy raro e inusual como te comento. Que efectúes un cambio tan grande como puede ser lo del color o de display inline-block que cambiaría completamente la forma de colocarse las cosas.

Answer (score 0):

Algo que podrías haber intentado era darle a ctrl+shift+r a ver si te cargaba el css corregido, asi fuerzas a la página a cargar completa ignorando la caché. Si no funciona, intenta colocar el style en la página .php o .html a ver si te lo aceptaba

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pude hacer es convertir tu `<div class="footer__content">` por un `<div class="container-fluid footer__content">` y quitarle la clase `container` a `<div class="container footer__container media">`, asi le da al contenido un espacio mas grande y tu `goals-text` le da oportunidad de ponerse en una sola linea.

Para mover el `goals-text` puedes usar la clase `ml-*` (* es de 1 a 5 para darle un margen izquierdo).

Answer (score 0):

Como va? Por lo que veo estas usando Bootstrap, el problema que veo es que no estas usando la estructura completa:

```
<footer>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6"> 
       <h4>EVERYTHING YOU NEED TO REACH YOUR GOALS</h4>
     <div> <!-- cerramos primer columna -->

     <div class="col-sm-6 text-right"> 
         <img src="../tuimagen.png" class="img-fluid" style="height:170px;">
         <a href="/online-programs" class="btn-primary">JOIN NOW</a>
     <div> <!-- cerramos segunda columna -->
   </div> <!-- cerramos el .row -->
</div> <!-- cerramos el .container -->
```

Con esta estructura ya tenes el contenido divido en 2, luego podes ajustar hacia a la izquierda o la derecha usando 2 cosas: El propio tamaño de la columna (ej: col-md-5) y los offset para "empujar" las columnas, esto lo podes ver en la documentacion de Bootstrap aqui Con esta estructura ya tenes el contenido divido en 2, luego podes ajustar hacia a la izquierda o la derecha usando 2 cosas: El propio tamaño de la columna (ej: col-md-5) y los offset para "empujar" las columnas, esto lo podes ver en la documentacion de Bootstrap aqui https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns

**Solo te quedaría agregar tus propias clases a las de Bootrstrap para darle tu propio estilo**, dejando que Bootstrap se encargue de la alineacion y preocupandote solo por los estilos de los objetos.